# Converting date from mm-dd-yyyy to MySql format with VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good day everyone.

This is another problem of mine. Since the first problem has been solved by the kind Sir Tim Schmelter. I would ask another set of questions. Thank you to those who will help

I have two problems:

My first problem now is with regards to the date. How do I convert the date from the text file so it would be inserted in the MySQL database? Its original form in the text file is ( 0246,04/16/2013,01:00,O ) and I don't know how to convert it

My second problem is I did change the values of the columns in the database to its rightful form (date to date, id to int) but whenever I try to change them in the 'MySqlDbType.' type it says that 'Index is outside the bounds of the array' and the error points to the code 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()'. I changed it from 'MySqlDbType.VarChar' to 'MySqlDbType.Date' and so on and when I put Int or Integer in it says that it isn't a part of the MySqlDbType.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\user\desktop\trial.txt"
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO swipe_table VALUES (@Emp_id, @Date, @Time)"

        Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)

        Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=cph;User ID=root;Password=;")
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, con)
                For Each line In allLines
                    Dim emp_id, dt, time As String
                    emp_id = line.Substring(0, 4)
                    dt = line.Substring(5, 10)
                    time = line.Substring(16, 4)
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    Dim pEmp_id As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Emp_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                    pEmp_id.Value = emp_id
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pEmp_id)
                    Dim pDate As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                    pDate.Value = dt
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate)
                    Dim pTime As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Time", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                    pTime.Value = time
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pTime)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                MsgBox("All records were inserted successfully")
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing true dates in your database then, regardless of the database, you need to convert your text into `DateTime` values in VB.NET.  Your ADO.NET provider will then worry about the rest.  To convert a `String` representation of a date into a `DateTime` you would use one of the `Parse`, `TryParse`, `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` methods of the `DateTime` type.

By the way, your date is apparently in MM/dd/yyyy format, not mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: I have a question sir, how do I convert the emp_id into integer? When I replaced that  VarChar with an Int or Integer it says that it isn't a type of the MySqlDbType.

Comment: How you convert the text to an `Integer` is a completely different problem to what `MySqlDbType` value to use.  Intellisense will tell you what members the `MySqlDbType` enumeration has so pick one from that list.  As for converting the data, it's much as it is for dates, i.e. use `Parse` or `TryParse` on the `Integer` type.

Answer (score 0):

I got it already, I just added a DateTime.ParseExact

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles `enter     MyBase.Load
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\user\desktop\trial.txt"
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO swipe_table VALUES (@Emp_id, @Date, @Time)"

    Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)

    Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=cph;User ID=root;Password=;")
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, con)
            For Each line In allLines
                Dim emp_id, time As String
                Dim dt As Date
                dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-05-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

                emp_id = line.Substring(0, 4)
                dt = line.Substring(5, 10)
                time = line.Substring(16, 5)
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                Dim pEmp_id As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Emp_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                pEmp_id.Value = emp_id
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pEmp_id)
                Dim pDate As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date)
                pDate.Value = dt
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate)
                Dim pTime As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@Time", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                pTime.Value = time
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pTime)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            MsgBox("All records were inserted successfully")
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    End Sub
    End Class
```